# How to import table's data in MySql from Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, sql-server-2008-r2, mysql-5.5, ssis

I am trying to export table from SQL Server 2008 R2 TO MySql 5.5. For this I am using `SQL Server Import and Export Wizard` of Sql Server 2008, but it is giving this error. [image: Error]

Here this error may be occurring because table in Sql Server has a column with data type `image` and table in MySql this column's data type is `LONGBLOB`.

Please provide your expert answers. If not possible through `SQL Server Import and Export Wizard` than please suggest any other method for data transfer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the datatype in SQL Server to VARBINARY(MAX) :

http://wiki.ispirer.org/sqlways/mysql/data-types/longblob

Even if this is just to get your data into SQL Server. It may also be worth noting that `IMAGE` is being removed in future editions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

QL Server databases are very Microsoft proprietary. Two options I can think of are:

1. Dump the database in CSV, XML or similar format that you'd then load into MySQL.
2. Setup ODBC connection to MySQL and then use DTS to transport the data. As Charles Graham has suggested, you may need to build the tables before doing this. But that's as easy as a cut and paste from SQL Enterprise Manager window to the corresponding MySQL window.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156279/how-to-import-a-sql-server-bak-file-into-mysql

Answer (score -2):

try to use following datatype for image in mysql
BLOB        L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16
MEDIUMBLOB  L + 3 bytes, where L < 2^24